# When removing lights from scene, currentLights value in renderer is not being decremented

Tags: three.js, webgl

So I have a situation where I have a webglRenderer and a scene and I am adding and removing lights from the scene. After adding 5 lights and removing them enough times, the renderer will crash because too many lights are registered in the webglRenderer. What I want to be able to do is reset the current number of lights value in the THREE.js webglRenderer when I remove the lights from the scene, so this problem does not happen. I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this or which variable I should be looking at in the THREE.js global scope.

I should note, that I have many objects that are also being added and removed along with the lights.

-Freddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not recommended.

In the Wiki article [How to Update Things with WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) it explained that properties that can't be easily changed in runtime (once a material is rendered at least once) include *numbers and types of lights*.

The article also provides suggested work-arounds.

three.js r.60